# How to write a mutex by key in bug free?

Tags: go, mutex

I want write a mutex with key just like https://github.com/im7mortal/kmutex ,but in different ideas.Just store the mutex in the hashmap.But there are always some deadlock in my code.How can I find the bug? Or are there better ways to write the key mutex?

```
package kmutex

import (
    "sync"
)

type keyMutex struct {
    localLockMap map[string]*sync.Mutex
    globalLock   sync.Mutex
}

func NewKeyMutex() *keyMutex {
    return &keyMutex{localLockMap: map[string]*sync.Mutex{}}
}

func (km *keyMutex) Lock(key string) {
    km.globalLock.Lock()

    wl, ok := km.localLockMap[key]

    if !ok {
        wl = &sync.Mutex{}
        km.localLockMap[key] = wl
    }

    km.globalLock.Unlock()

    wl.Lock()
}

func (km *keyMutex) Unlock(key string) {
    km.globalLock.Lock()

    wl, ok := km.localLockMap[key]

    if !ok {
        km.globalLock.Unlock()
        return
    }

    delete(km.localLockMap, key)

    km.globalLock.Unlock()

    wl.Unlock()
}
```

and test code is below

```
func TestKeyMutex1(t *testing.T) {

    keyMutex := kmutex.NewKeyMutex()

    //var keyMutex sync.Mutex

    var count = 0

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var num = 100

    for i := 1; i <= num; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            keyMutex.Lock("a")
            count += i
            keyMutex.Unlock("a")
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    println(count)

}
```

There are always deadlock in it.After I remove the line `delete(km.localLockMap, key)`.The deadlock is gone! But I still cannot understand it

Comment: There is a better key mutex algo used in kubernetes/utils

Answer (score 4):

The problem is indeed deleting the mutex in the map.

Considering just have three locks in the same entry (`"a"` in your case) running in the following order (in multiple goroutines, of course):

```
keyMutex.Lock("a") // lock1
keyMutex.Lock("a") // lock2
keyMutex.Lock("a") // lock3
keyMutex.Unlock("a") // unlock1
keyMutex.Unlock("a") // unlock2
keyMutex.Unlock("a") // unlock3
```

`lock1` creates a mutex in the map, and then `lock2` and `lock3` acquire the same mutex, blocking on the Lock of the mutex. `unlock1` finds the mutex, unlocks it and removes it from the map, unblocking `lock2` (or `lock3`, but for discussion's sake, let's say it is `lock2`). But when `unlock2` or `unlock3` runs, it finds no mutex in the map, unlocking nothing, and keeps `lock3` blocking, thus a deadlock.

The line removing mutex from the map simply don't make sense: a mutex is re-usable and in the context it is only sensible to have a same mutex for same entry.

Comment: Thx for reply.I would'd expect there are multiple lock before unlock.After your explain,I finnally understand that.

Removing mutex is just for release memory for unused key

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) as well where the mutex primitives are abstracted for you.
From the official documentation,

> Map is like a Go map[interface{}]interface{} but is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines without additional locking or coordination. Loads, stores, and deletes run in amortized constant time.